# HBM2DDl_AUTO cannot be resolved to a variable in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am following a tutorial on Spring MVC and Angular. I have created a field in db.properties for HBM2DDL_Auto as follows:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

But when I try to configure in AppConfig.java like below:

```
props.put(HBM2DDl_AUTO, env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
```

I get the following error in Eclipse:

```
HBM2DDl_AUTO cannot be resolved to a variable
```

It is not showing like that in the tutorial video. Why is it showing like that for me?

Comment: Have you declared a variable HBM2DDl_AUTO  in your class?

Comment: No. I have not. It was not declared in the tutorial. I just declared it in db.properties file as shown in the question.

Comment: I do not get an error if I define it like this:
`props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));`

Comment: In the above case you won't get error because, it is a string. Look into tutorial carefully for the above variable declaration.

Comment: I got it! I had declared HBM2DDl_AUTO instead of HBM2DDL_AUTO. Silly mistake. My bad!